# sort the query depends on the data in an array

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

In one condition, sort the query depends on the objectId in the array.If the objectId is in the arraym, i want show it top.My code

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"pinUser" ]; //Normal Sort
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                  ------
                  ---------
    }
}];
```

I want to change the change the normal sort to my requirement.

Comment: you need to sort `objects` in block again apart from `[query orderByDescending:@"pinUser" ];`?

Comment: "pinUser" is a array... only sort if the "PinUser" array contain the "objectId"

Answer (score 0):

Apply your sorting on resulted objects in block. u can check the objectId of objects in ur arrayM or not on resulted array of objects , not with PFQuery